# How to send emails to multiple users in magento2?

Tags: magento2, email

I am trying to send email to single user means it's working fine.How can i send to multiple user?

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder
           ->setTemplateIdentifier('my_email_template')
           ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
           ->setTemplateVars($vars)
           ->setFrom($sender)
           ->addTo($toEmail)
           ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try this below code.

if you want send to multiple email address you can use array format like

`$emails = ['email1@test.com', 'email2@test.com'];`

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
            ->setFrom('from@email.com')
            ->addTo($emails)
            ->setReplyTo('reply@email.com')
            ->addBcc('test@email.com')
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: More than 5 mails means how can I add?Is that any array format available?

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan - you can send through array format if more than one email. like $emails = ['email1@test.com', 'email2@test.com'];

Comment: @Jjo, where to put this `$emails` variable ?